# Deep query to nested types in GraphQL return NULL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, graphql

Have a strange problem...

Query to nested types return null.

But, if I return anything in parent type - resolve return right result

My code:

```
import { GraphQLList, GraphQLString, GraphQLID, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import AdminModel from '../models/Admin.model';

const AdminType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AdminType',
    fields: {
        _id: { type: GraphQLID },
        login: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString }
    }
});

const AdminRooteType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AdminRooteType',
    fields: {
        getAdmins: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AdminType),
            resolve() {
                return AdminModel.find({})
            }
        }
    }
})

export default new GraphQLSchema({ 
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'RootQuery',
        fields: {
            admin: {
                type: AdminRooteType,
                resolve() {
                   // EMPTY RESOLVE - EMPTY RESULT
                }
            }
        }
    })
 });
```

Query:

```
{
  admin {
    getAdmins {
      login
    } 
  }
}
```

Result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "admin": null
  }
}
```

If I changed returned value in fields admin in RootQuery:

```
import { GraphQLList, GraphQLString, GraphQLID, GraphQLObjectType, GraphQLSchema } from 'graphql';
import AdminModel from '../models/Admin.model';

const AdminType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AdminType',
    fields: {
        _id: { type: GraphQLID },
        login: { type: GraphQLString },
        password: { type: GraphQLString }
    }
});

const AdminRooteType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'AdminRooteType',
    fields: {
        getAdmins: {
            type: new GraphQLList(AdminType),
            resolve() {
                return AdminModel.find({})
            }
        }
    }
})

export default new GraphQLSchema({ 
    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name: 'RootQuery',
        fields: {
            admin: {
                type: AdminRooteType,
                #resolve() {#
                    #// RETURN ANYTHING HERE:#
                  #  return 'foobar'#
                }
            }
        }
    })
 });
```

I've got expected result:

```
{
  "data": {
    "admin": {
      "getAdmins": [
        {
          "login": "123"
        },
        {
          "login": "12asdf3"
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

What is right solution for this issue? (without using dummy values in return)

Thank's a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are seeing is the expected behavior. Imagine we have a `User` type with some fields:

```
const UserType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'User',
  fields: {
    id: { type: GraphQLID },
    name: { type: GraphQLString },
  }
})
```

And a way to fetch a single user:

```
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    user: {
      type: AdminRooteType,
      resolve: () => getUser(),
    },
  },
})
```

If `getUser` returns an object representing a `User`, the resolvers for all the fields (i.e. `id` and `name` on the `User` type will be called.

When those fields (and whatever child fields they might have) resolve, you end up with a User object for the entire `user` field to return. A response might look something like:

```
"data": {
  "user": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Maria",
    "comments": [
      {
        "id": 1,
        // and so on...
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Now, consider what happens when a user is not found and we return null instead. Our response looks like this:

```
"data": {
  "user": null
}
```

It doesn't make sense to call any of the resolvers for the User fields. Would you expect the API to still return an `id` or `name` in this case? If it did, what values would those fields have? If we just returned a null `id` and `name`, how would the client distinguish that object from a User that existed but really did have `id` and `name` null values?

The point is, if a field returns a GraphQLObjectType and it resolves to null, none of the resolvers on the GraphQLObjectType will be called.

By unnecessarily nesting your `getAdmins` field inside another GraphQLObjectType, you're forced to return some kind of object inside the resolver for `admin`. So you will need to either live with that, or avoid creating an `AdminRootType` altogether and just put the `getAdmins` field on your Query type directly, as per convention:

```
const QueryType = new GraphQLObjectType({
  name: 'Query',
  fields: {
    getAdmins: {
      type: new GraphQLList(AdminType),
      resolve: () => AdminModel.find({}),
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Thank's a lot, Daniel!
Main idea was group my queries and mutations by type(admin, articles, subscribers etc). I thought it's do my structure more clear