# Skipping over a resolver for a query

Tags: graphql, apollo, apollo-server

I have a basic query in GraphQL set up like this:

```
type Article {
  title: String
  // more primitives, not important though
}

type News {
  sourceOne: [Article]
  sourceTwo: [Article]
}

type Query {
  news: News
}
```

I have a resolver for news on my top level query but I don't need it. My sources for news are two distinct and unrelated urls. I don't want to fetch an entire collection of news stories for both sources if the graphql request only asked for one source or the other.

Is there some way to skip the news resolver? Right now I have it defined as `news: () => ({})` because leaving it off results in a null field returned.

My question is, can I skip a parent resolver and still have the children resolvers called? Is this a horrible way to set up multiple sources of news articles? I'm relatively new to GraphQL so I'd love to hear a better way to tackle this.

I'm using NodeJS and ApolloServer.

Comment: This question's been asked in one form or another several times already. Please see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54641506/6024220), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54219592/6024220) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54463837/6024220). Short answer, this sort of approach breaks convention and I would caution against it. There's no way to do what you're trying to do without returning an empty object in the resolver for `news`.

Comment: You've been extremely helpful, thanks!