# Why doesn't this GraphQL property return as expected when I'm calling it's parent?

Tags: graphql, apollo

So I'm trying to build an app to iterate through bookmarks which I have stored on Google Firestore. I'm accessing Firestore through an Apollo server.

Here are my resolvers and type definitions.

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-server-express';
import * as admin from 'firebase-admin';

const serviceAccount = require('./service-account.json')
admin.initializeApp({
    credential: admin.credential.cert(serviceAccount)
});

// Locations of bookmarks in database
const bookmarks = admin.firestore().collection("bookmarks");

export const typeDefs = gql`
type Bookmark {
    name: String
    url: String
    preview: Preview
}

type Preview {
    bookmark: Bookmark
    description: String
    image: String
}

type Query {
    bookmarks: [Bookmark]
    hello: String
}

schema {
    query: Query
}
`;

export const resolvers = {
    Query: {
        hello(obj, args, context, info) {
            return 'Hello world!'
        },
        async bookmarks() {
            const firebaseList= await bookmarks.get();
            return firebaseList.docs.map(bookmark => bookmark.data());
        }
    },

    Preview: {
        description: () => "this is a description",
    }
};
```

When I send this query:

```
{bookmarks{
  name
  url
  preview {
    description
  }
}}
```

I want it to return the description of the preview (obviously) but I get

```
{
  "data": {
    "bookmarks": [
      {
        "name": "Google",
        "url": "https://google.com",
        "preview": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Facebook",
        "url": "https://facebook.com",
        "preview": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Instagram",
        "url": "https://instagram.com",
        "preview": null
      },
      {
        "name": "Pinterest",
        "url": "https://pinterest.com",
        "preview": null
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

What am I misunderstanding about how GraphQL works?

Comment: Does the data being returned from firebase for each bookmark contain a property named `preview`?

Comment: no, it doesn't, though it wasn't by oversight. My goal for this code was to eventually have it populate the `preview` property with Open Graph Meta tags-taking the `url` as a parameter without having to store all of that data into Firebase.

My first solution was to do this in the browser, but I ran into CORS so I'm trying to figure out the best way to do that on the server.

Comment: This is effectively the same problem as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54216527/trigger-nested-resolvers-with-graphql/54219592) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54634344/deep-query-to-nested-types-in-graphql-return-null). You need to add a resolver for the `preview` field that returns an empty object. For more details, see the answers in the aforementioned posts.